# Cosa significa "stronarsi"?

Tags: verbs, word-meaning

Questo brano appartiene al libro *Le certezze del dubbio* di Goliarda Sapienza:

> Quasi mi dispiace, e se avessi un qualche soldo in più allungherei la corsa per continuare a *stronarmi* con questo ennesimo compagno di strada. Fu a Parigi, credo, che chiacchierai tutta la notte con un vecchio taxista oriundo nizzardo e che all'alba non mi fece sconti ma mi offrì in un locale speciale - non so in quale periferia - i croissants più buoni che abbia mai assaporato.

Non capisco cosa significhi "stronarsi": ho cercato il vocabolo nei dizionari, ma non l'ho trovato. Qualcuno di voi potrebbe spiegarmelo?

**Aggiornamento:**

Infatti, previo a questo brano, c'è un altro esempio di uso del verbo "stronarsi" nel dialogo tra Goliarda e il taxista (che parla un po' in romanesco):

> «Caldo eh, signora? Se cominciamo ad aprile cost'afa chi ci arriva a settembre!»
>
> «Non è solo caldo, amico, è che ho bevuto e m'ero scordata di fare colazione...»
>
> Il taxista per me è come un confessore o un analista, non c'è pudore che resista alla loro sapienza dei fatti raccolti per la strada. Perché mentire quando è chiaro che hanno visto tutto?
>
> Infatti dallo specchietto retrovisore - come sapevo - un gran sorriso comprensivo mi viene incontro, mentre la voce calda romana dice rassicurante: «E che male c'è! Fa bene *stronarsi* qualche volta! Aiuta a sopportà sto monnaccio che non dico, l'avemo voluto noi, ma ciò malgrado voluto o non voluto ce punisce a tutti i 'na maniera troppo esagerata, nun è così?»

Comment: Non conosco il termine, ma ci vedo un misto tra lo “stonare” già ricordato in una risposta e “rintronare”. (Oppure è un errore di stampa! :-) )

Comment: @DaG: Forse si tratta di "stordirsi" (per l'alcool, per la lunga chiacchierata col taxista...) ma in un modo piacevole.

Comment: Non è una variante che ho mai sentito, ma l'uso che l'autore ne fa mi pare proprio che coincida con "stonarsi" usato spesso come sinonimo gergale di "stordirsi", come hai correttamente immaginato. Non penso, invece, che ci sia, nella parola in sé, una particolare sfumatura che indichi il "modo piacevole", che risulta eventualmente solo dal contesto.

Answer (score 1):

Penso si riferisca al fatto di **parlare tanto da diventare "*stonato*"**. Il riferimento a lunghe chiacchierate notturne è chiaro in "*chiacchierai tutta la notte con un vecchio taxista"*:

Stonare:

> - v.intr. (aus. avere) [sogg-v] Andare fuori tonalità, provocando un suono sgradevole. (Sabatini Coletti)

Oppure : [stonare](http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/S/stonare.php):

> - Provocare un senso di malessere, di stordimento: il lungo viaggio lo aveva stonato. (Repubblica)

Quindi, *parlare tanto fino allo sfinimento, allo stordimento.*

Answer (score 1):

*Stronato* è una versione dialettale per frastornato, stordito, intontito, rintronato, spesso messo in relazione con l'uso/abuso di alcool.

Nel centro Italia e in Sardegna è un termine colloquiale abbastanza diffuso.

Comment: Per curiosità, tu di dove sei? A Roma non l'ho mai sentito, ma non metto in dubbio la tua esperienza.

Comment: Ancona. Da noi si usa, e mi è capitato di sentirlo anche da amici laziali...

Comment: Si usa tranquillamente anche in Liguria